# Issue synchronizing multiple countdown timers with Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.9

I'll start by saying that I'm completely new to tkinter and I've been trying to wrap my head around a minor issue I'm experiencing - it might be very simple/I'm approaching it incorrectly, but some insight would be very appreciated!

Essentially I have an app with multiple items, each item has a button. When you click a button for an item, it starts a countdown timer by calculating the duration in a function, then using `.after(1000, ...)` to refresh my label every second.

The issue is, when you click on a button and start a timer, it counts down every second from when the button is clicked. So if you click the next button "off cycle" from the last countdown, the countdown is NOT SYNCED up the way it should be.

Currently it counts down a second from when the button is pressed, instead of updating every "true second", if that makes sense. Any idea how I can approach this?

```
def handle_growth_time(n, harvest_time):
    time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_now = time_now.replace(microsecond=0)
    crop = allotments[n]

    if not crop["reset"]:
        if harvest_time >= time_now:
            remaining_time = harvest_time - time_now
            crop["remaining_label"].configure(text=remaining_time, font='ariel 12', foreground="black")
            crop["remaining_label"].after(1000, handle_growth_time, n, harvest_time)
        else:
            crop["label_name"].configure(background="#86d474")
            crop["active"] = False
    else:
        crop["reset"] = False
        crop["active"] = False
```

I have tried a couple different approaches, such as when I capture `time_now` I grab `time_now.microseconds/1000` and waiting for that before starting the countdown but I think working with time in that way is unreliable because I still can't really capture true :00.00
I also tried resetting all the timers when a new one is started, refreshing their 1 sec cycle, but I did so by going through an array and restarting them - as you can imagine this causes them to be offset still.

Comment: Do you realize that tkinter, like every other GUI engine I know, updates the screen asynchronously?  And all modern operating systems use multithreading, so your program can get pre-empted by another program at any time.  The exact time when the screen updates is out of your control.  You simply cannot arrange to flash the time on the screen with millisecond precision.  Having said that, how would your users know the exact instant that the internal OS timer value ticks over?  Why not create a reasonable-looking time display, even if it's slightly fictionalized?

Comment: @PaulCornelius I'm not very familiar with GUI engines so no, I literally did not know that but I do now lol.

I'm not sure if I properly understand the last part of what you're saying. I'm not asking for anything from the user, I'm telling my timers to tick down after waiting 1 second, but I currently see no way to have them match up - even if just forcing them to restart at the same time or something?

Perhaps one of your points went over my head.

Comment: Getting them all to match up means updating them in one place. 
I see you already know about the `after` function - how about using `after` to run a function each second, and from that function updating all the timers together?  You might have to keep track of start times for each individual timer or something like that.  Without seeing your whole program I can't be more specific.

Comment: That's a good point, I was thinking that as a solution as well but I couldn't exactly wrap my head around how to have it run through all the timers. Basically I have an array of a couple different dictionaries. Each dictionary has some information about an item including its "harvest_time". I calculate the timer countdown from harvest_time - time_now. The only way I could think of to have a single function updating every second also update the timers would be checking through a loop to see if the timer should be active or not. Which would inherently take time to run through the loop,

Comment: Throwing the whole thing off. No?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having only a single timekeeper that keeps track of passing seconds. Each timer can have a `tick` function that is called by this single timer. It is then responsible for updating all timers at the same time so that the update at the same time.

The following example illustrates the point.  It's not production quality code, but it illustrates the point: multiple timer objects that all "tick" during a single time loop.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Timer(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, seconds):
        super().__init__(parent, text=str(seconds), width=8)
        self.time = seconds
        self.running = False

    def tick(self):
        self.time -= 1
        self.configure(text=self.time)
        if self.time == 0:
            self.running = False

    def start(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

class Timekeeper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timers = []

    def new_timer(self, seconds):
        t = Timer(root, seconds)
        t.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.timers.append(t)
        t.start()

    def tick(self):
        root.after(1000, self.tick)

        # update existing timers
        for timer in self.timers:
            if timer.running:
                timer.tick()

timekeeper = Timekeeper()
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x600")
button_15 = tk.Button(root, text="New 15 second timer", command=lambda: timekeeper.new_timer(15))
button_30 = tk.Button(root, text="New 30 second timer", command=lambda: timekeeper.new_timer(30))
button_15.pack(side="top")
button_30.pack(side="top")

# add a few timers as an example
timekeeper.new_timer(15)
timekeeper.new_timer(30)
timekeeper.new_timer(45)
timekeeper.new_timer(60)

root.after(1000, timekeeper.tick)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Bryan! Having one single timekeeper was something that I thought of initially I just didn't really have the know-how. Also if this isn't production quality, I'd be ashamed to show how I was trying to get something similar working ;) lol

Really appreciate this bit of code! Tomorrow I'm going to spend some time analyzing it, I think I'll be able to learn a lot from it, this seems like the correct approach